# Caffe always gives the same prediction in Python, but training accuracy is good

Tags: python, caffe, pycaffe

I have a trained model with caffe (through the command line) where I get an **accuracy of 63%** (according to the log files). However, when I try to run a script in Python to test the accuracy, I get all the predictions in the same class, with very similar prediction values, but not quite identical. My goal is to compute the accuracy per class.

Here are some examples of predictions:

```
[ 0.20748076  0.20283087  0.04773897  0.28503627  0.04591063  0.21100247] (label 0)
[ 0.21177764  0.20092578  0.04866471  0.28302929  0.04671735  0.20888527] (label 4)
[ 0.19711637  0.20476575  0.04688895  0.28988105  0.0465695   0.21477833] (label 3)
[ 0.21062914  0.20984225  0.04802448  0.26924771  0.05020727  0.21204917] (label 1)
```

Here is the prediction script (only the part which gives the predictions for a specific image):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
import os
import caffe

caffe.set_device(0)
caffe.set_mode_gpu()

# Prepare Network
MODEL_FILE = 'finetune_deploy.prototxt'
PRETRAINED = 'finetune_lr3_iter_25800.caffemodel.h5'
MEAN_FILE = 'balanced_dataset_256/Training/labels_mean/trainingMean_original.binaryproto'

blob = caffe.proto.caffe_pb2.BlobProto()
dataBlob = open( MEAN_FILE , 'rb' ).read()
blob.ParseFromString(dataBlob)
dataMeanArray = np.array(caffe.io.blobproto_to_array(blob))
mu = dataMeanArray[0].mean(1).mean(1)



net = caffe.Classifier(MODEL_FILE, PRETRAINED,
                       mean=mu,
                       channel_swap=(2,1,0),
                       raw_scale=255,
                       image_dims=(256, 256))

PREFIX='balanced_dataset_256/PrivateTest/'
LABEL = '1'
imgName = '33408.jpg'
IMAGE_PATH = PREFIX + LABEL + '/' + imgName

input_image = caffe.io.load_image(IMAGE_PATH)
plt.imshow(input_image)


prediction = net.predict([input_image])  # predict takes any number of images, and formats them for the Caffe net automatically
print 'prediction shape:', prediction[0].shape
plt.plot(prediction[0])
print 'predicted class:', prediction[0].argmax()
print prediction[0]
```

The input data is **grayscale**, but I convert it to **RGB** by duplicating the channels.

Here's the architecture file finetune_deploy.prototxt:

```
name: "FlickrStyleCaffeNetTest"
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Input"
  top: "data"
  # top: "label"
  input_param { shape: { dim: 1 dim: 3 dim: 256 dim: 256 } }
}
layer {
  name: "conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 96
    kernel_size: 11
    stride: 4
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "conv1"
}
layer {
  name: "pool1"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "pool1"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "norm1"
  type: "LRN"
  bottom: "pool1"
  top: "norm1"
  lrn_param {
    local_size: 5
    alpha: 0.0001
    beta: 0.75
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "norm1"
  top: "conv2"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 256
    pad: 2
    kernel_size: 5
    group: 2
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 1
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu2"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "conv2"
}
layer {
  name: "pool2"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "pool2"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "norm2"
  type: "LRN"
  bottom: "pool2"
  top: "norm2"
  lrn_param {
    local_size: 5
    alpha: 0.0001
    beta: 0.75
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv3"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "norm2"
  top: "conv3"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 384
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu3"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv3"
  top: "conv3"
}
layer {
  name: "conv4"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv3"
  top: "conv4"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 384
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    group: 2
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 1
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu4"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv4"
  top: "conv4"
}
layer {
  name: "conv5"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv4"
  top: "conv5"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 256
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    group: 2
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 1
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu5"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv5"
  top: "conv5"
}
layer {
  name: "pool5"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv5"
  top: "pool5"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "fc6"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "pool5"
  top: "fc6"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 4096
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.005
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 1
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu6"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "fc6"
  top: "fc6"
}
layer {
  name: "drop6"
  type: "Dropout"
  bottom: "fc6"
  top: "fc6"
  dropout_param {
    dropout_ratio: 0.5
  }
}
layer {
  name: "fc7"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "fc6"
  top: "fc7"
  # Note that lr_mult can be set to 0 to disable any fine-tuning of this, and any other, layer
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 4096
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.005
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 1
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu7"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "fc7"
  top: "fc7"
}
layer {
  name: "drop7"
  type: "Dropout"
  bottom: "fc7"
  top: "fc7"
  dropout_param {
    dropout_ratio: 0.5
  }
}
layer {
  name: "fc8_flickr"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "fc7"
  top: "fc8_flickr"
  # lr_mult is set to higher than for other layers, because this layer is starting from random while the others are already trained
  param {
    lr_mult: 10
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 20
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 6
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "prob"
  type: "Softmax"
  bottom: "fc8_flickr"
  top: "prob"
}
```

Comment: How did you get the caffemodel file in .h5 format?

Comment: That's how it was generated during training, by specifying snapshot_format: HDF5 in the solver

Comment: Are you sure this format can be read in by the python script? Can you check the weights to see that it is proper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out,
the deploy.prototxt had some input_param mismatch.

Strange behavior.